# Android: PopupWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView) -> how to get the whole screen as a anchorView?

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html), which I'd like to place in the center of the screen. However, I only have access to the [KeyboardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) (since I'm implementing an [IME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html)) at the bottom of the screen and whenever I center my `PopupWindow` by using the `KeyboardView` and `Gravity.CENTER` it is of course only centered above the keyboard, but not in the whole screen.

Is there a way to get the whole screen as an anchor view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with a popup window. You should create your own window using a WindowManager instance.

Comment: Okay, will look into that. You know if there is some example code around?